# Evaluating Telescopic Sum $ \sum\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How to evaluate following
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}$$
I posted my way as an answer, Is there another **Interesting approach** to evaluate this sum of series?

Comment: The parenthesing change you make from line two to line three *has* to be justified as in the general case it is false. Why in this case it certainly is correct? And for another way: isn't the above already pretty simple and straightforward?

Comment: @Timbuc Is it not okay to learn new ways to do things?

Comment: It certainly usually is, @DigitalBrain : why?

Comment: This a nice problem ! From you answer, I suspected that $\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}$ should be the ratio of two polynomials of same degree. I just played with regression and my surprise has been to find $$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}=\frac{p^2+p}{2 \left(p^2+p+1\right)}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici my answer?

Comment: I like it ! Well done. Your answer inspired me and I looked for the partial sums in a very empirical manner (I am not a mathematician). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way

$x$<sup>th</sup> Term of this sum can be written as 
$$T_x=\frac{x}{1+x^2+x^4}=\left(\frac {1}{2\cdot(x^2-x+1)}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot(x^2+x+1)}\right)$$
Similarly $(x+1)$<sup>th</sup> Term can be written as
$$T_{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{1+(x+1)^2+(x+1)^4}=\left(
\frac{1}{2\cdot(x^2+x+1)}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot(x^2+3x+3)}\right)$$
So,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{21}+\frac{3}{91}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\infty}\\
&=
\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{14}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{14}-\frac{1}{26}\right)+
\cdots
\left(\frac{1}{\infty}-\frac{1}{\infty}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+
\left(-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+
\left(-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{14}\right)+
\cdots
\left(\frac{1}{\infty}-\frac{1}{\infty}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+
\left(0\right)+
\left(0\right)+
\cdots
\left(0\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}=\frac{1}{2}$$