# Summation of $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{r}{1+r^2+r^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please compute $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{r}{1+r^2+r^4}$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: A few similar posts [found using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Br%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Br%7D%7B1%2Br%5E2%2Br%5E4%7D%24&p=1): [Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1645776), [Evaluate $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^{4}+n^{2}+1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/571973) or [Evaluating Telescopic Sum $ \sum\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4} $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/973217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+1)^2-r^2=\left(r^2+1-r\right)\left(r^2+1+r\right)=\left(r^2+r+1\right)\left(r^2-r+1\right)\implies$$

$$\frac r{r^4+r^2+1}=\frac r{\left(r^2+r+1\right)\left(r^2-r+1\right)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{r^2-r+1}-\frac1{r^2+r+1}\right)$$

So now do the telescopic sum:

$$\frac12\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac1{r^2-r+1}-\frac1{r^2+r+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1-\frac13+\frac13-\frac17+\frac17-\ldots\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

Since $(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1=k^2+k+1$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{(k^2+1)^2-k^2}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{(k^2-k+1)(k^2+k+1)}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2-k+1}-\frac1{k^2+k+1}\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k^2+k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+k+1}\right)\tag{4}\\[4pt]
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{0^2+0+1}\right)\tag{5}\\[8pt]
&=\frac12\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write the denominator as a difference of squares
$(2)$: write the difference of squares as a product
$(3)$: partial fractions
$(4)$: separate the sums and substitute $k\mapsto k+1$ in the left-hand sum
$(5)$: retain only the uncancelled ($k=0$) term
$(6)$: evaluate